# Caption content dependent on table name

Tags: tables, captions

I have a table environment with a set caption.

I want the caption to be singular for tables with one row and plural for tables with multiple rows, all using the same environment.

Is that achievable and if so, how can I achieve it?

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=large,font=bf,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\newenvironment{Content}{\caption*{Contents}
\begin{tabular}{ll}}{\end{tabular}\vspace{0\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{Content}
test1 & test1 (want the caption for this one to be 'Content' instead)\\
\end{Content}

\begin{Content}
test2 & test2\\
test2 & test2\\
\end{Content}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Why same environment? Easiest is to use two environments `content` and `contents`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=large,font=bf,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\newenvironment{Content}{\zz\caption*{Content\mys}
\begin{tabular}{ll}}{\end{tabular}\vspace{0\baselineskip}}
\def\zz#1\\#2{%
\ifx\end#2\def\mys{}\else\def\mys{s}\fi#1\\#2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{Content}
test1 & test1 (want the caption for this one to be 'Content' instead)\\
\end{Content}

\begin{Content}
test2 & test2\\
test2 & test2\\
\end{Content}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Normally the `\\` on the last row is optional and best omitted, but here you need it otherwise you'll get a runaway argument error.